# python - Creating an addon, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, add-on, error

I'm trying to make an addon in 2.81 and for some reason I'm getting this error:

```
register_class(...): 
Warning: 'dp.clear_menu' doesn't contain '_MT_' with prefix & suffix
register_class(...):
Warning: 'dp.ui' doesn't contain '_PT_' with prefix & suffix
```

I have no idea what "dp" is. Here's the link to what I have:

https://github.com/kojocrash/Blender-Weld-Plugin

Comment: Recommend matching `bl_idname` to the class name.   eg `class WELD_OT_create(...)` and `bl_idname = "weld.create"`  The error message you are seeing is warning about the class naming convention.  It has nothing to do with the addon code you posted, rather some other addon you have enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Visual Studio Code to run & test my addon and it got fixed for one of these 3 reasons:

1. I ran VS Code as an administrator
2. I reinstalled python (but checked the PATH option)
3. I installed the ptvsd as done in [this video](https://youtu.be/UVDf2VSmRvk?t=174)